# md-autocomplete not filtering?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm trying to get the `md-autocomplete` from [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) library to work, the documentation is a bit hard to understand.

Here's my html

```
<md-autocomplete
  md-items="lawyer in cdc.lawyers"
  md-selected-item-change="testing(lawyer)"
  md-min-length="0"
  md-item-text="lawyer.name"
  md-search-text="cdc.lawyerSearchText"
  md-search-text-change="cdc.triggerQuery(cdc.lawyerSearchText);"
  placeholder="Search for lawyer">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="cdc.lawyerSearchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{lawyer.name}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
  <md-not-found>
    No states matching "{{lawyer.name}}" were found.
  </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

and here's the javascript

```
this.lawyerSearchText = '';

this.triggerQuery = function(query){
  console.log(query);
  this.lawyerSearchText = query;
}
```

It displays all the `lawyers` but does not filter them if I type gibberish in the input.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your query logged to the console from your triggerQuery function?

Comment: yes it is, the characters typed in

Answer (score 2):

I pass the population of the list through the filter function, so your `md-items` would be:

```
md-items="lawyer in cdc.triggerQuery(cdc.lawyers")
```

and then I am normally making an $http call to retrieve a filtered list there, but in your case I think in your triggerQuery function you would return the filtered array. Something like:

```
this.triggerQuery = function(query){
    return this.lawyers.filter( function(lawyer) { return lawyer.indexOf(query)>-1) })
}
```

but where you are using query, I am using the `ng-model` value the autocomplete is bound to. If that's not enough post all the relevant parts of your controller and I can expand this.